# Requiring non-file assets with webpack

Tags: javascript, audio, webpack

I'm having trouble understanding how to accomplish this using Webpack. I am writing a cross-platform (web, iOS, Android, desktop) application that uses a lot of sound files, but I cannot determine the file type I'm going to need until runtime because of inconsistent audio format support.

In order to deal with this, all of my sounds are stored as .wav files, and I batch convert them to mp3 and ogg then decide at runtime which I'm going to use. This is where the issue with Webpack appears. I'd like to be able to `require(some/sound/file)` without an extension and have the loader return resolve two paths (one for each converted format).

Is it possible to use `require` with Webpack without specifying an actual file (or files)?